# Create parameters for command Linux shell script

Tags: linux, shell

Hello I am trying to create parameters for my shell script but I am having trouble.

lets say for example the file is called test.

When I call `./test -parameter1 input_file.txt`
I get an error saying 'no such file or directory'.

Here is an example of my code.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" == "parameter" ]
then
    while read line
    do
        #echo "$line"
    done <$1
else
    echo "Not working"
fi
```

My over all goal of this is to read in a file of numbers line by line which I have working, then to calculate the average values of the rows or by columns. Which is why I am trying to create parameters so the user will have to specify `./test -rows input_file.txt` or `./test -columns input_file.txt`

Comment: It would be clearer if you named your script `[` instead of `test`.  (That is an attempt at subtle humor, what I really mean is that you should not name your script `test`, since that is commonly a shell builtin and keeping that name will only lead to confusion.)

Comment: I have my script called 'stats', was just using 'test' as a generic example. Thanks for the input though, I just started learning and practicing making Linux shell scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the string `-parameter` as the input file name.  Perhaps you want:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" = "-parameter" ]
then
    while read line
    do
        #echo "$line"
    done <$2   # Use $2 instead of $1 here.  Or use shift
else
    echo "Not working" >&2
fi
```